# Insert an value in the search box and select the dropdown option

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Can anyone guide me on how to handle this below scenario through selenium.

Expected workflow: System should automatically type "125" in the search box and select value "patient ID"

Comment: Share the code that you have tried.

Comment: Since I am new to this python, from google I tried to apply CSS selector. But it was not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this id is unique :

```
searchinput
```

You can use the below code to send `125`

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchinput"))).send_keys('125')
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Update 1 :**

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("frame id"))
#then interact with `searchinput`
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for your help. While executing query system is throwing below error

Comment: TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ceb5f4723874> in <module>
     22 #CLINICALS.click()
     23 wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
---> 24 wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "searchinput"))).send_keys('125')
     25 
     26 
c:\users\kganesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)

Comment: 81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):
TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Can you try this instead `driver.find_element(By.ID, "searchinput").send_keys('125')`  ?

Comment: Hi , tried above code but it is throwing below error..

NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="searchinput"]"}

Comment: hmm, Is page url public ? if not, can you look for iframe ? I am guessing that this element could be in an iframe

Comment: It is a public URL, but it is accessible only when we login into VPN connection. Regarding iframe, could not see any word with text "iframe" in HTML source. Have shared screenshot of the HTML above. Once again, I appreciate your guidance.

Comment: Can you give me page resource as well  ? You need to save the source code into a text file, then upload that text file using file sharing website (free ofcourse). they will give you a sharable link. That link you can give me.

Comment: Hi, sharing code will be against our company policies. I hope you understand my situation.. Thanks

Comment: Hi, while discussing with my friend I can came to know that above ID is built under iframe "GlobalNav"

Comment: @Ganesh : well that was my guess too (read above comments), anyway I have updated the answer above, in case it was useful or solves your issue, you can you accept & upvote (click on voting button) this answer so that it will be available in green color for future readers. In case if you would like to accept this answer, please feel free click on check mark which is right aside with voting buttons. I'd appreciate your time and response on this. –